# Incorrect IP address returned to Java program and code running in tomcat

Tags: java, linux, networking, ip-address

OS: `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)`
Java `jdk1.8.0_45` standalone program and code running in tomcat is returning wrong IP address for few host names.
Correct IP is returned by dig and nslookup on the same machine.
Using `strace -s 2048 -o strace_log -ff` did not yield any useful information for troubleshooting.
Using `-Dsun.net.spi.nameservice.nameservers=8.8.8.8` or the local DNS server (used by nslookup and dig) returns same incorrect address.

```
[INFO]  sun.net.InetAddressCachePolicy.get() = 30
[INFO]  sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1 = null
[INFO]  sun.net.spi.nameservice.nameservers = 8.8.8.8
```

Using [dnsjava](http://www.xbill.org/dnsjava/) with `-Dsun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1="dns,dnsjava"` returns correct IP address.

How can I check which name server java is actually using?
Or any more techniques for troubleshooting?

Thanks

Test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

HOST=REMOVED

NAMESERVER=LOCAL_NAME_SERVER_IP
NAMESERVER=8.8.8.8

# -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \ #-Dsun.net.spi.nameservice.nameservers=$NAMESERVER \
# -javaagent:dnslog.jar \
# -Dsun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1="dns,dnsjava" \
# -cp ".:./dnsjava-2.1.8.jar" \

javac Test.java

rm strace_log.*
strace -s 2048 -o strace_log -ff java \
     -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
     -Dsun.net.spi.nameservice.nameservers=$NAMESERVER \
     Test https://$HOST

dig $HOST > ${HOST}_dig.txt
nslookup $HOST > ${HOST}_nslookup.txt
java -cp "./dnsjava-2.1.8.jar" dig $HOST > ${HOST}_dnsjava.txt
```

Test.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.logging.*;

public class Test extends Formatter {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName());
    log.setUseParentHandlers(false);

    ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler();
    handler.setFormatter(new Test());
    log.addHandler(handler);

    log.info("sun.net.InetAddressCachePolicy.get() = " + sun.net.InetAddressCachePolicy.get());
    log.info("sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1 = " + System.getProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1"));
    log.info("sun.net.spi.nameservice.nameservers = " + System.getProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.nameservers"));

    try {
      if (args.length != 1 && args.length != 2) {
        log.warning("Usage: java Test <https://address.server.edu> [timeout]");
        return;
      }

      log.info("Received host address " + args[0]);
      URL constructedUrl = new URL(args[0]);
      String host = constructedUrl.getHost();

      InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
      String ip = address.getHostAddress();
      log.info("Host = " + args[0] + " IP = " + ip);

      InetAddress Address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
      log.info("InetAddress.getLocalHost() = " + Address);
      log.info("InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() = " + Address.getCanonicalHostName());

      InetAddress SW[] = InetAddress.getAllByName(host);
      for (int i=0; i < SW.length; i++) {
        log.info("getAllByName[" + i + "] = " + SW[i]);
      }

      URLConnection conn = constructedUrl.openConnection();

      if (args.length == 2) {
        conn.setConnectTimeout(Integer.valueOf(args[1]) * 1000);
      } else {
        conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
      }
      log.info("Setting connection timeout to " + conn.getConnectTimeout() / 1000 + " second(s).");

      log.info("Trying to connect to " + args[0]);
      InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);

      in.readLine();
      in.close();
      reader.close();

      log.info("Great! It worked.");

    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.info("Could not connect to the host address " + args[0]);
      log.info("The error is: " + e.getMessage());
      log.info("Here are the details:");
      log.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);

      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  public String format(LogRecord record) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    sb.append("[");
    sb.append(record.getLevel().getName());
    sb.append("]\t");

    sb.append(formatMessage(record));
    sb.append("\n");

    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: @jww Thanks for your comment. Code is added to the question.

Comment: Looking at strace output closely looks like nscd "name service cache daemon" could be the culprit. Did not see UDP message going out to port 53.

Comment: `getent ahosts HOST_NAME` confirmed that nscd has the wrong value cached. Still need to find why DNS TTL is not honored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was resolved by restarting nscd daemon. It was kind of hung as in there were many `nscd -i hosts` processed running, but it was still responding to queries from app. That probably explains why DNS TTLs were not honored.